# Rails AJAX login without devise or authlogic

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a site build using Ruby on Rails 4.2.0. The live version is available at [ALXS Design](http://alxs.co.uk). In my development version, I have a hand-made login system, which works perfectly. I have tried to implement AJAX into a login link in the sidebar, which I have working. However, when I log out and then click the log in link, the form appears twice, sometimes three times. If I refresh the browser window, the form appears only once, as it is supposed to.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

sessions_controller.rb:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
         session[:user_id] = user.id
         respond_to do |format|
           format.html { redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully" }
           format.js
         end      
       else
         respond_to do |format|
           format.html { flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination" }
           format.js
         end

         render :action => 'new'
       end
     end

     def destroy
       reset_session
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You have successfully logged out." }
         format.js
       end
     end
   end
```

new.html.erb:

```
    <div id="login-form">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <%= form_tag session_path do %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= label_tag :email %><br />
          <%= text_field_tag :email %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= label_tag :password %><br />
          <%= password_field_tag :password %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

new.js.erb

```
    $("<%= escape_javascript render(file: 'sessions/new.html.erb') %>").insertAfter('.login-link');

    $('#login-form').hide().slideDown();
    $('.login-link').hide();
```

_navigation.html.erb

```
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="toggle-menu">
          <a class="show-me menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">
            <i class="fi-arrow-left" alt="Menu Toggle" style="text-align: right; width: 100%;"></i>
            <span class="fi-arrow-right" alt="Menu Toggle"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
          ALXS Design
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to root_path do %>Home<span class="fi-home" alt="Home"></span><% end %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to about_path do %>About<span class="foundicon-website" alt="About"></span><% end %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to projects_path do %>Projects<span class="fi-folder" alt="Projects"></span><% end %>
        </li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
        <br />
        <li>
          <%= link_to new_article_path do %>New Article<span class="fi-add-doc" alt="New Article"></span><% end %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Edit Password", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
        </li>
        <% else %>
        <br />
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Login", login_path(@user, :format => :js), :remote => true, class: 'login-link' %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Register", register_path %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
        <li>
          <div class="navigation-padding"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="hide-me">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alxsdesign" target="_blank">Facebook<span class="fi fi-social-facebook"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="hide-me">
          <a href="https://github.com/tipsforthings" target="_blank">Github<span class="fi fi-social-github"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="hide-me">
          <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/116471654573031381012/posts/p/pub" target="_blank">Google+<span class="fi fi-social-google-plus"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="hide-me">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/alxsdesign" target="_blank">Twitter<span class="fi fi-social-twitter"></span></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

destroy.js.erb

```
    $('.login-link')[0].reset();
```

I think it maybe something to do with the destroy action in the sessions controller, or the destroy.js.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

Your link_to is getting the new action for the session controller and appending it to the page. You want to have the content on the page already and then make the form submit using Ajax.

Comment: What is the best way to do this?